# Ordering by ACF custom field vaule

Tags: custom-field, order

I'm using ACF field for post ordering. Now I have positions for 1-5 for post display, so you can select on which position post should appear. Only thing that I can't achieve right now for example is when you choose positon 1, all values on another posts should change by +1. So if you select first positon, post which was on first postion should change acf value to position 2. For example if you select positon 3, post that was on position 3, 4 and 5 should change value to 4, 5 and 6.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Ordering by postmeta values (like ACF values) is slow. You would be better off in the long run to use a custom taxonomy instead. However, if you want to keep using the postmeta, you could set up an ACF options page where you select one post for each of your numbers. That way you always have 1 post for each number, rather than having to try to update postmeta for other posts when you update it for one. That would be very, very slow.

Comment: Hi Elaine, thanks for answer. So you suggested to me to avoid such upating post meta value? Is there any other solution to accomplish this? Basically there is 5 position in slider and they should be in some relationship. If the new post is on position 2nd other should move by +1. Some drag and drop ordering pluing etc. Thanks for helping

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned you could use a custom taxonomy, perhaps named "order", to identify what order they go in. However that would not be drag and drop. If you want drag and drop and you don't mind sticking with postmeta, create an ACF options page and set up the fields there, instead of on individual posts. That way you don't have to update multiple posts.